# Javascript, print the global object from a static function

Tags: javascript, methods, static-methods

With the following code, how can the method `my_method` be called so that it prints the global object (window) ?

```
 MyClass = function() {
      this.my_method = function() {
         console.log(this);
      }
  }
  var myobject = new MyClass();
```

This is not an homework, but a question that I've been asked and that I can't understand because  i don't know in deep JavaScript.

So, if someone can help me understand and give me a well explained answer I will be happy !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the function to null :

```
MyClass = function() {
      this.my_method = function() {
         console.log(this);
      }
  }
  var myobject = new MyClass();
  myobject.my_method = myobject.my_method.bind(null);
  myobject.my_method(); // this will log the DomWindow object
```

That's because when the context of a function is null or undefined, `this` is the global object.

From the [ECMAScript reference](http://es5.github.com/#x10.4.3) :

> 1. If the function code is strict code, set the ThisBinding to thisArg.
> 2. Else if thisArg is null or undefined, set the ThisBinding to the global object.

Answer (score 2):

You can also make use of [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to change the context of the function.

```
var myobject = new MyClass();
myobject.my_method.call(this);
myobject.my_method.apply(this);
```

This may work nicely if you don't need a permanent binding or you want a dynamic change of context.